# Can I ask questions about brewing equipment, but not necessarily brewing?

Tags: discussion

Would I be able to ask this question on homebrew.stackexchange.com?

"I have a an issue where my hydrometer is stuck in my carboy. I can't reach it with my hand to get it out. Any ideas on how to get it out?"

Answer (score 3):

I'd say yes; just for example, looking at the `carboy` tag has several unclosed questions relating to equipment and not directly brewing beer.

Examples:
[Carboy Dimensions](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/carboy-dimensions) 
[Class Carboy vs Better Bottle](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1240/glass-carboy-vs-better-bottle)
[Carboy Cap vs Stopper](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3250/carboy-cap-vs-stopper)
[Adding oak chips to a carboy](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/adding-oak-chips-to-a-carboy) (specifically, getting them out)

Also, while looking through these, there's even an `equipment` tag you could use.

(Although, might rephrase it to "How can I get it out" vs "Any ideas," so it's more directly answerable instead of discussion. Of course, that's nitpicky.)

Comment: +1 agreed, this is on topic. Also thanks for attempting to remove discussion